# How to use a form data object to send an image from a responsive mobile site to a server

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am updating a website that has a responsive mobile version. A user creates a profile that includes an image. In the browser version, all of the data including an image are uploaded. In the responsive version, all the data except the image are uploaded. It is my understanding from what I've learned on this site and others that I must use a getElementById() and a formData object to get an image from the mobile site to the server. In addition to the resources I've found in StackOverflow, I'm using code by Eric Bidelman of gist.githum.com. After many attempts, I can't get it to work. My formData code does not work, and I'm not sure how to integrate it into the existing code. I appreciate any help with these two problems.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I'm working with.

```
<form id="form" name="form" action="post.php" method="post" onsubmit="return check_inputs();" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
             <fieldset>
                <legend>About Me</legend>

                <label>Email:</label><input data-theme="a" name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $email?>" maxlength="30" /><span id="s1">*</span>                
                <label>Image:</label><input data-theme="a" id="image" name="image" type="file"  accept="image/*" <?php echo $image?>" size="30" /> 

                xhr.send(FormData).html

            </fieldset> 
            <fieldset>
            <input data-theme="a" data-ajax="false" name="submit" class="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </fieldset>
</form>

post.php

//code to resize image file and send to images folder.

//code to write data to the database.

xhr.send(FormData).html
<script>
  document.getElementById('image').addEventListner('change', function(e){
    var file = this.files[0];
    var fd = new FormData()
    fd.append('image', file);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('POST',handle_file_upload.php, true);

    xhr.onload = function(){
        if (this.status == 200{
            var reso = JSON.parse(this.response);

            console.log('Server got:', resp);

            var image = document.createElement('img'):
            image.src = resp.dataUrl;
            document.body.appendChild(image);
        };
    };
    xhr.send(fd);
}, false);
</script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src = "http:ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
<script>CFInstall.check({mode: 'overlay'});</script>
<![endif]-->:

handle_file_upload.php
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$dataUrl = 'data:' . $fileType . ';base64,' . base64_encode($fileContent);

$json = json_encode(array(
'name' => $fileName,
'type' => $fileType,
'dataUrl' => $dataUrl,
));

echo $json;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have additional double quote.

Make it

```
<input data-theme="a" id="image" name="image" type="file"  accept="image/*" <?php echo $image?> size="30" />
```

(quotes before size= removed)

Also, why do you need the  in there?

Comment: Clearly, a typo error on my part.  It should be value="<?php echo $image?>"